# NLTK and cx_Freeze issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, cx-freeze

I'm deploying a simple Tkinter application that takes care of processing a word file and returning a txt file with tokenized words. The main ingredients are Tkinter and NLTK.

After creating the building folder with cx_Freeze, I found several problems.
When I try to launch the resulting exe file on another pc with Windows installed, the console lists that 'punkt' is not available.

I tried to insert the following code block immediately after the import of nltk:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import os
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')     #HERE 
nltk.download('stopwords') #ALSO HERE
import string
from collections import Counter
import win32com.client
from pywintypes import com_error
```

This is the piece of code of imports and here is where it later goes into error, during execution:

```
pathToProc = self.originalFile.get()
sent_tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/italian.pickle')
snt = nltk.stem.SnowballStemmer('italian')
it_stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('italian') + ['\n', '\t', '']
trashes = it_stop_words + list(string.punctuation)
tokensTOT = []
try:
    myDoc = word.Documents.Open(pathToProc, False, False, True)                 
    sentences = sent_tokenizer.tokenize(word.ActiveDocument.Range().Text)
    myDoc.Close()
    del myDoc
    for sentence in sentences:
        tokensTOT = tokensTOT + nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
except com_error:
    print('IMPOSSIBILE DECIFRARE IL FILE')
```

The following is the code I used to create the build folder, aimed to being copied and pasted on all windows computers.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os, sys

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\AOUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\AOUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\tcl\tk8.6'

include_files = [r"C:\Users\AOUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",
                 r"C:\Users\AOUP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs\tk86t.dll",
                 r"C:"]
packages = ["os", 
            "tkinter", 
            "nltk", 
            "string", 
            "collections", 
            "win32com.client", 
            "pywintypes",
            "socket"]
setup(
    name = 'Bea Tokenizer',
    version = "2.5",
    description = "Simple Tkinker tokenizer window",
    options = {"build_exe": {
               'packages': packages,
               'include_files': include_files,
               'include_msvcr': True,
               }},
    executables = [Executable("beaTokenizer.py", base = None)]
)
```

Despite having entered `nltk.download('punkt')` and 
`nltk.download('stopwords')` the error this time is different:

```
[nltk_data] Error loading punkt: <urlopen error unknown url type:
[nltk_data] https>
[nltk_data] Error loading stopwords: <urlopen error unknown url type:
[nltk_data] https>
```

I wonder why nltk lends itself so badly to deploying, despite being a widely used and continuously developing framework.

I hope I've been clear and correctly explained the answer.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the nltk packages you need in the setup script into a specific destination folder, let cx_Freeze include this folder into the frozen application, and use the same folder for the nltk packages in your main application, which should then find the packages already downloaded.

Add the following lines to your setup script (used to create the build folder according to your description):

```py
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='nltk_packages') 
nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir='nltk_packages')
include_files = ['nltk_packages',
                 # add here further include_files items you need
                ]
```

and modify the download calls in your main script:

```py
nltk.download('punkt', download_dir='nltk_packages') 
nltk.download('stopwords', download_dir='nltk_packages')
```

I'm not able to test this answer (probably because of proxy limitations), but as far as I can judge from the source code of nltk, this or a similar solution should solve your problem. You might need to tweak the destination folder paths passed to `download_dir` and `include_files` according to the behavior of nltk.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution proposal. At the next deployment I'll try to do as you wrote. I'm convinced that it'll certainly be better ;)

Comment: I tried the various experiments you suggested me. Unfortunately they didn't work... and I see the errors yet...